# How to exclude some layers from ArcReader legend?

Tags: arcmap, arcreader

I have created an ArcReader map for staff which has a number of imagery layers, such as satellite imagery and a raster topographic map. I also have a legend which automatically updates based on which layers are selected in the table of contents. How do I exclude the imagery layers, though, because they are not useful in a legend? When they appear in a legend they are just RGB colours.

Comment: woops, actually this is easy. just select from map layers list the ones you want as candidates for the legend. send all of these across to the legend items list. click the 'only display layers that are checked...' box. voi la

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as you discovered (five years ago), is as simple as ticking the box in the Legend settings that says "Only display layers that are checked on in the Table Of Contents".

[image]